# ¿Como mostrar y ocultar todo un container?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Necesito que apenas comience el video se muestre el contenido de el contenedor y cuando este a punto de acabar se oculte, el video dura 10 segundos, en la imagen esta el contenedor:

```css
*{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
    .container-main {
      position: relative
    }
    
    .container-main video {
      width: 100%;
      display: block;
      min-height: 100px;
    }
    
    .container-main .img {
      position: absolute;
      top: 20%;
      max-width: 300px
    }
    
    .img-1 {
      right: 10%;
    }
    
    .medellin{
        position: absolute;
        right: 16%;
        top:12%;
        color: white;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 40px;
    }
    .grado{
        position: absolute;
        right: 16%;
        top:57%;
        color: white;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 70px;
    }
    .dia{
        position: absolute;
        right: 9%;
        top:73%;
        color: white;
        font-family: Arial;
    }
    .hora{
        position: absolute;
        right: 16%;
        top:85%;
        color: white;
        font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

  <title>pieza clima</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" type="text/css">

  
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-main">
    <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
        <source src="img/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    <img src="iconos/Soleado.png" class="img img-1" />
    <h1 class="medellin">Medellín</h1>
    <h1 class="grado">17ºC</h1>
    <h1 class="dia">Martes, 19 de febrero</h1>
    <h1 class="hora">4:30 p.m.</h1>


    </div>
</body>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe un evento para cuando un video finaliza,
ejemplo:

```
var myvideo= document.getElementById("MyVideo");
myvideo.onended = function() {
    alert("el video ha terminado");
//tu funcion de ocultar el container aqui.
};
```

saludos.